# ng-bind-html is failing for compound variable expressions

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am writing an angular front end with Typescript.
I need to bind html for correct rendering. I use ng-bind-html for this purpose.

It works fine with simple variables like

```
 <span ng-bind-html='property'></span>
```

Correct text is rendered in the app.

But now I have a very complex variable

```
{{notification.getTranslationKey() | translationNamespace:parentctl.getTranslationNamespace() | translate}}
```

I tried different ways of using ng-bind-html with this expression but it is not working. I get just empty space instead of my text.

How to use ng-bind-html with such complex expressions? Are there alternatives to this approach? May be it is possible to bind html in controller instead of html?

Comment: You get "empty space", not any error, that means the directive works alright. Plus, the code seems alright to me too. So first need to make sure its not a bug in your `notification.getTranslationKey()` code. If it returns empty space, or if it returns alright but ends up as empty space after going through pipes, then you ask about wrong thing. Please confirm that first.

Comment: Well, it works when I remove ng-bind-html, the sentence is rendered but I need to use ng-bind-html for rendering apostrophe (I use &apos; and I need to bind html because the phrase resides in an rfs-component), so there is no problem with notification.getTranslationKey(), it just does not work in combination with ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) to access filters in the controller:

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
     var p1 = $scope.notification.getTranslationKey();
     var arg1 = $scope.parentctl.getTranslationNamespace();
     var p2 = $filter("translationNamespace", p1, arg1);
     var p3 = $filter("translate", p2);
     console.log(p3)
     return p3;
});
```

#### Usage

```
<span ng-bind-html='myFunc()'></span>
```

Then one can use standard debugging techniques to diagnose problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it out tomorrow